# pc wont boot with sd card reader plugged in

Tags: sd-card

when i installed 12.04 on new hdd i didnt have the card reader plugged in before partitioning, now that my gateway zx4000 is all set up i realized the card reader hadnt been plugged in so now when i try to plug it in while my pc is on the system will power off and when i reboot it gives me some kind of error message and wont reboot until i unplug the card reader, any help is appreciated. (card reader is where you insert video/photo sd card correct?)

Comment: I had a similar problem with my notebook. Bios was set to boot from a CD/DVD first, but if there was a non-bootable disk in the drive, it tried and failed to boot from the DVD (the Incredibles, I believe) and then never booted at all. See if you can change the boot settings to make sure you're booting from your hard disk first. I know it's not a fix, but it might be a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

It would help a lot if you could tell the exact error message you received. This issue could have multiple causes:

- the BIOS might be set to boot from USB before trying the hard disk, so check the BIOS settings
- your /etc/fstab might list the partitions to be mounted with /dev/sdx syntax - unfortunately, those are not fixed, what is /dev/sda on one boot might be /dev/sdb on the next. Therefore Ubuntu usually uses block ids instead of absolute device paths, with "UUID=..." syntax. If your fstab has absolute paths, you could replace them with the block ids. To find out which block id belongs to e.g. sda1 type:

  user@host:~$ **blkid -s UUID /dev/sda1**
  /dev/sda1: UUID="0123456789ABCDEF"

and then replace /dev/sda1 in your fstab with UUID=0123456789ABCDEF (without quotes).